# zlib error when creating a new project in angular

Tags: angular

I am new to angular. I am trying to create a project in angular. I installed node js using the binaries. I also installed angular cli using npm.

C:\Users\JETSS>ng new test-app2
? Would you like to add Angular routing? Yes
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS
CREATE test-app2/angular.json (3795 bytes)
CREATE test-app2/package.json (1316 bytes)
CREATE test-app2/README.md (1025 bytes)
CREATE test-app2/tsconfig.json (408 bytes)
CREATE test-app2/tslint.json (2837 bytes)
CREATE test-app2/.editorconfig (245 bytes)
CREATE test-app2/.gitignore (503 bytes)
CREATE test-app2/src/favicon.ico (5430 bytes)
CREATE test-app2/src/index.html (295 bytes)
CREATE test-app2/src/main.ts (372 bytes)
CREATE test-app2/src/polyfills.ts (3234 bytes)
CREATE test-app2/src/test.ts (642 bytes)
CREATE test-app2/src/styles.css (80 bytes)
CREATE test-app2/src/browserslist (388 bytes)
CREATE test-app2/src/karma.conf.js (964 bytes)
CREATE test-app2/src/tsconfig.app.json (166 bytes)
CREATE test-app2/src/tsconfig.spec.json (256 bytes)
CREATE test-app2/src/tslint.json (314 bytes)
CREATE test-app2/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
CREATE test-app2/src/environments/environment.prod.ts (51 bytes)
CREATE test-app2/src/environments/environment.ts (662 bytes)
CREATE test-app2/src/app/app-routing.module.ts (245 bytes)
CREATE test-app2/src/app/app.module.ts (393 bytes)
CREATE test-app2/src/app/app.component.html (1173 bytes)
CREATE test-app2/src/app/app.component.spec.ts (1104 bytes)
CREATE test-app2/src/app/app.component.ts (213 bytes)
CREATE test-app2/src/app/app.component.css (0 bytes)
CREATE test-app2/e2e/protractor.conf.js (752 bytes)
CREATE test-app2/e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json (213 bytes)
CREATE test-app2/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts (305 bytes)
CREATE test-app2/e2e/src/app.po.ts (208 bytes)
**npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.5.9: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, fl
atted is its successor.
npm ERR! code Z_BUF_ERROR
npm ERR! errno -5
npm ERR! zlib: unexpected end of file**

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\JETSS\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-11-07T08_35_16
_253Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.

C:\Users\JETSS>

I have highlighted the error in **Bold**. Also shown below are the details in the log file

**3297 verbose stack ZlibError: zlib: unexpected end of file
3297 verbose stack     at Zlib.(anonymous function).onerror (C:\Users\JETSS\node-v10.13.0-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minizlib\index.js:131:21)
3297 verbose stack     at Unzip.write (C:\Users\JETSS\node-v10.13.0-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minizlib\index.js:255:31)
3297 verbose stack     at Unzip.flush (C:\Users\JETSS\node-v10.13.0-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minizlib\index.js:222:10)
3297 verbose stack     at Unzip.end (C:\Users\JETSS\node-v10.13.0-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minizlib\index.js:229:10)
3297 verbose stack     at Object.end (C:\Users\JETSS\node-v10.13.0-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:415:21)
3297 verbose stack     at PassThrough.onend (_stream_readable.js:628:10)
3297 verbose stack     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
3297 verbose stack     at PassThrough.emit (events.js:187:15)
3297 verbose stack     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1094:12)
3297 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)**
3298 verbose cwd C:\Users\JETSS\test-app1

Any clue on what could be the reason?

Comment: Why do you tag `asp.net` and `asp.net-core`?

Comment: I am planning to use this angular project in asp .net core project. I am a .Net developer and when I tried to use the Visual studio angular template for asp .net core it was not working well. So my colleagues asked me to create an angular project using angular CLI and it gave the above error message